# Difficulty with unique_lock in simple Producer & Consumer

Tags: c++, c++11, producer-consumer, unique-lock

I have written a very simple Producer/Consumer based out of C++11 notes and unable to figure out why the unique_lock() does not release the lock when goes out of scope.

```
struct Message{
Message(int x):data(x){cout<<"+";}
int data;
};


queue<Message*> g_queue;
condition_variable cv;
mutex m;

void consumer()
{
    do {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck {m};
        cv.wait(lck, [&](){return !g_queue.empty();});
        cout<<"Notified...";
        auto& obj = g_queue.front();
        std::cout<<obj->data;
        g_queue.pop();
        cout<<".";
        lck.unlock(); -----(1)
    } while(1);

}

void producer() 
{
    while(true){
            unique_lock<mutex> lck {m};
            Message msg{5};
            cout<<"Queue size:"<<g_queue.size()<<'\n';
            g_queue.push(&msg);
            cv.notify_one();
            lck.unlock(); -------(2)
            cout<<"-"<<'\n';
            this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{2000});
    }
}
```

And use it as:-

```
    thread Q(&consumer);
    thread P(&producer);
    P.join();
    Q.join();
```

The output is:-

```
+Queue size:0
-Notified...
5.+Queue size:0
-Notified...5
.+Queue size:0
-Notified...5
```

So technically, yes, Producer needs to tell Consumer that I am ready and Consumer needs to let Producer know send more data. I am not clear on what to use, does condition variable does this or does unique_lock does this.

Precisely, why I need (1) and (2) when the scope can release the locks

==Edit==
Following is the edited code, which works fine,

```
void consumer()
{
    do {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck {m};
        cv.wait(lck, [&](){return !g_queue.empty();});
        cout<<"Notified...";
        auto& obj = g_queue.front();
        std::cout<<obj->data;
        g_queue.pop();
        cout<<".";
    } while(1);

}

Message msg{5};
void producer() 
{
    while(true){
            unique_lock<mutex> lck {m};
            cout<<"Queue size:"<<g_queue.size()<<'\n';
            g_queue.push(&msg);
            cv.notify_one();
            cout<<"-"<<'\n';
    }
}
```

Now, how do I introduce a little throttle if I want to in Producer or Consumer if sleep is risky ?

Comment: You don't need (1). You need (2) because otherwise `producer` holds the lock while sleeping, thereby starving `consumer`. Also, your program exhibits undefined behavior: it populates `g_queue` with pointers to local variables which may very well be destroyed by the time the pointer is retrieved and dereferenced.

Comment: yes, I understand it now. Starving is the cause of the behavior I could see when I was running with removing (1) and (2) both. So I removed the sleep statement and could see context switch in the output. Also, I could understand the local variable issue and have rectified it in my code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there's still a question here, but one solution for throttling is to have a maximum size the queue is allowed to grow to in the producer. When the queue reaches this size, the producer waits on a different condition variable. The consumer signals this second condition variable when the queue drops below a certain size. (The latter size perhaps being somewhat less than the maximum to give some hysteresis.) The predicate for the wait on this new condition variable is `g_queue.size() >= max_size`.

Comment: yes this was still a question. So for throttling we need 2 new CV to manage the queue buffer emptiness and fullness.At this point, when not yet starting to think about optimization, I can re-write the code above to use the throttle management. Let me try and come back here again. Thank you.